# Parsing xml to group multiple child elements based on having the same subchild element value?

Tags: xml, xml-parsing

I'm trying to parse an XML file that is generated from our system where there are multiple child elements generated, but are "together" since they have a subchild element that is the same.

To make sense of the partial xml code I pasted below...

Each record is identified by it's order # and then it contains info for that shipment and at the end lists an individual item that's for that order with it's specs.

```
<forward_agent>
    <record>
      <order>562490</order>
      <mfg._del_date>11-19-2008</mfg._del_date>
      <forw.agent>263</forw.agent>
      <customer>120</customer>
      <name>BLUEBERRY AUBURN HILLS</name>
      <item>&apos;28.1461.00</item>
      <ordered>1.0000</ordered>
      <warehouse>001</warehouse>
      <desitnation_city_state>AUBURN HILLS  MI</desitnation_city_state>
      <weight>60.1201</weight>
      <size>9.70</size>
</record>
<record>
      <order>562490</order>
      <mfg._del_date>11-19-2008</mfg._del_date>
      <forw.agent>263</forw.agent>
      <customer>120</customer>
      <name>BLUEBERRY AUBURN HILLS</name>
      <item>&apos;545</item>
      <ordered>1.0000</ordered>
      <warehouse>002</warehouse>
      <desitnation_city_state>AUBURN HILLS  MI</desitnation_city_state>
      <weight>82.0120</weight>
      <size>12.86</size>
</record>
<record>
      <order>&#160;</order>
      <mfg._del_date>&#160;</mfg._del_date>
      <forw.agent>&#160;</forw.agent>
      <customer>&#160;</customer>
      <name>&#160;</name>
      <item>&apos;</item>
      <ordered>&#160;</ordered>
      <warehouse>&#160;</warehouse>
      <desitnation_city_state>Total Lbs:</desitnation_city_state>
      <weight>1658.1342</weight>
      <size>199.36</size>
</record>
    <record>
      <order>562136</order>
      <mfg._del_date>11-19-2008</mfg._del_date>
      <forw.agent>263</forw.agent>
      <customer>133</customer>
      <name>BLUEBERRY ALBUQUERQUE</name>
      <item>&apos;4635</item>
      <ordered>2.0000</ordered>
      <warehouse>002</warehouse>
      <desitnation_city_state>EL PASO  TX</desitnation_city_state>
      <weight>23.9863</weight>
      <size>4.00</size>
</record>
<record>
      <order>562136</order>
      <mfg._del_date>11-19-2008</mfg._del_date>
      <forw.agent>263</forw.agent>
      <customer>133</customer>
      <name>BLUEBERRY ALBUQUERQUE</name>
      <item>&apos;5590</item>
      <ordered>1.0000</ordered>
      <warehouse>002</warehouse>
      <desitnation_city_state>EL PASO  TX</desitnation_city_state>
      <weight>0.0000</weight>
      <size>0.00</size>
</record>
<record>
      <order>562136</order>
      <mfg._del_date>11-19-2008</mfg._del_date>
      <forw.agent>263</forw.agent>
      <customer>133</customer>
      <name>BLUEBERRY ALBUQUERQUE</name>
      <item>&apos;5591</item>
      <ordered>1.0000</ordered>
      <warehouse>002</warehouse>
      <desitnation_city_state>EL PASO  TX</desitnation_city_state>
      <weight>436.0082</weight>
      <size>96.67</size>
</record>
<record>
      <order>&#160;</order>
      <mfg._del_date>&#160;</mfg._del_date>
      <forw.agent>&#160;</forw.agent>
      <customer>&#160;</customer>
      <name>&#160;</name>
      <item>&apos;</item>
      <ordered>&#160;</ordered>
      <warehouse>&#160;</warehouse>
      <desitnation_city_state>Total Lbs:</desitnation_city_state>
      <weight>5093.0928</weight>
      <size>613.88</size>
</record>
```

I'd like the output to be grouped by Order # and look something similar to this:

```
Item         Ordered    Weight          Size
1221         1          320.6734        31.36
1601         1          34.0724         11.42
2122         1          86.0023         12.79
5543.SP      1          1075.254        121.23
28.1461.00       1          60.1201         9.7
545              1          82.012          12.86
            Total Lbs:  1658.1342       199.36
```

Ultimately this is so that I can sort out orders based on total weight and size or a particular item.

---EDIT---

Shows input boxes now, but they aren't getting filled with anything.

**Current js code**

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "b2.xml",
    dataType: "xml",
    success: function(response) { parseXML(response); }
  });
});

var recordList =[];

function parseXML(xml) {
$(xml).find('record').each(function () {
    var entry = new Object();
    entry.order= $(this).find('order').text();
    entry.delDate= $(this).find('mfg._del_date').text();
    entry.forw = $(this).find('forw.agent').text();
    entry.customer= $(this).find('customer').text();
    //
    //

    recordList.push(entry);

});
send(); // handles xml after parsed
}

function send(){
     // for each row of a table
     for(var i = 0; i < $("#table tr").size(); i++){
         $('#orderNum' + i).val(recordList[i].order);
         $('#delDate' + i).val(recordList[i].delDate);
         $('#forw' + i).val(recordList[i].forw);
         $('#customer' + i).val(recordList[i].customer);
     }
 }
```

**Current html code**

```
    <html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="parser.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Order #</td>
        <td>Delete Date</td>
        <td>Forward</td>
        <td>Customer</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input id="orderNum0" type="text" /></td>
        <td><input id="delDate0" type="text" /></td>
        <td><input id="forw0" type="text" /></td>
        <td><input id="customer0" type="text" /></td>
    </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Here's a screenshot:

http://s16.postimage.org/rd1uahm4j/localhost_ftl_parser_html.png

Comment: change the success method.. refer to my code i added the ajax call

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Record.js**

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$.ajax({
type: "GET",
url: "record.xml", 
dataType: "xml",
success: function(xml){
    parseXML(xml); 
},
error: function(response, textStatus, errorThrown){ 
    console.log(textStatus, errorThrown);}
   });
});

var recordList =[];

function parseXML(xml) {
$(xml).find('record').each(function () {
var entry = new Object();
entry.order= $(this).find('order').text();
entry.delDate= $(this).find('mfg').text();
entry.forw = $(this).find('forw').text();
entry.customer = $(this).find('customer').text();
entry.name = $(this).find('name').text();
entry.item = $(this).find('item').text();
entry.ordered = $(this).find('ordered').text();
entry.warehouse = $(this).find('warehouse').text();
entry.destination = $(this).find('desitnation_city_state').text();
entry.weight = $(this).find('weight').text();
entry.size = $(this).find('size').text();

recordList.push(entry);
});
send(); // handles xml after parsed
}

function send(){
 // for each row of a table
 addRows();
 for(var i = 0; i < recordList.length; i++){
     $('#orderNum' + i).val(recordList[i].order);
     $('#delDate' + i).val(recordList[i].delDate);
     $('#forw' + i).val(recordList[i].forw);
     $('#customer' + i).val(recordList[i].customer);
     $('#name'+i).val(recordList[i].name);
     $('#item'+i).val(recordList[i].item);
     $('#ordered'+i).val(recordList[i].ordered);
     $('#warehouse'+i).val(recordList[i].warehouse);
     $('#destination'+i).val(recordList[i].destination);
     $('#weight'+i).val(recordList[i].weight);
     $('#size'+i).val(recordList[i].size);

     }
  }

 function addRows(){
      for(var i = 1; i < recordList.length; i++){
         var newField = "<tr><td><input id=\"orderNum"+i+"\" size=\"10\" type=\"text\"    </td>"+
                        "<td><input id=\"delDate"+i+"\" size=\"10\" type=\"text\"</td>"+
     "<td><input id=\"forw"+i+"\" size=\"10\" type=\"text\"</td>"+
     "<td><input id=\"customer"+i+"\" size=\"10\" type=\"text\"</td>"+
     "<td><input id=\"name"+i+"\" size=\"10\" type=\"text\"</td>"+
     "<td><input id=\"item"+i+"\" size=\"10\" type=\"text\"</td>"+
     "<td><input id=\"ordered"+i+"\" size=\"10\" type=\"text\"</td>"+
     "<td><input id=\"warehouse"+i+"\" size=\"10\" type=\"text\"</td>"+
     "<td><input id=\"destination"+i+"\" type=\"text\"</td>"+
     "<td><input id=\"weight"+i+"\" size=\"10\" type=\"text\"</td>"+
     "<td><input id=\"size"+i+"\" size=\"10\" type=\"text\"</td></tr>"

     $('#tableId').append(newField);
        }
   }
```

**Record.html**

```
      <html>
     <head>
     <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
      <script type="text/javascript"   src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
       <script type="text/javascript" src="records.js"></script>
   </head>
<body>
<table id="tableId">
    <tr>
        <td>Order #</td>
        <td>Delete Date</td>
        <td>Forward</td>
        <td>Customer</td>
    <td>Name</td>
    <td>Item</td>
    <td>Ordered</td>
    <td>Warehouse</td>
    <td>Destination</td>
    <td>Weight</td>
    <td>Size</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><input id="orderNum0" size="10" type="text" /></td>
    <td><input id="delDate0" size="10" type="text" /></td>
    <td><input id="forw0" size="10" type="text" /></td>
    <td><input id="customer0" size="10" type="text" /></td>
<td><input id="name0" size="10" type="text" /></td>
<td><input id="item0" size="10" type="text" /></td>
<td><input id="ordered0" size="10" type="text" /></td>
<td><input id="warehouse0"size="10"  type="text" /></td>
<td><input id="destination0" type="text" /></td>
<td><input id="weight0"size="10"  type="text" /></td>
<td><input id="size0" size="10" type="text" /></td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

There is only one issue and that is with your xml entries with the name of forw.agent and mfg.del_date.. you'll have to escape some of those characters but this adds rows and adds values to those tables.. this is a rough page thrown together and you have liberties to change things as you please.. especially the input box's you can change those to labels or what have you.. but this parses and displays.. as per requested

Comment: then for the printing of the column you can handle it however you want

Comment: How would you recommend printing the column?  
I tried:
$('#output').append($(this).find('customer').text());
But that doesn't do what I want it to do...  I'm still learning and experimenting

Comment: are you printing to a webpage? or a doc?

Comment: I can't get it to work.  I edited my post to show you my current code.  Right now it's only outputting the input boxes on the webpage with no values populating them.  Thanks for your help DWolf

Comment: unless you have it in there, i just couldnt see it.. its using alot of jquery.. also if you look at your console when u are trying all this u should be able to follow it and see errors

Comment: I changed the ajax call and the jquery source was already in the header (I just didn't paste it here).  But still nothing happens.  I added a link to a screenshot of what I'm seeing.

Comment: open your console and run the program and see if there are any errors